# Android Ajax Request

Tags: android, ajax, jquery

I have searched a lot my question but for nothing... I have this ajax jquery request :

```
pan=6;
tilt=0;
zoom=0;
duration=1000;
jQuery.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "//"+ip+"/cgi-bin/momentary_movement.cgi",
   dataType: "xml",
   data: "pan="+pan+"&tilt="+tilt+"&zoom="+zoom+"&duration="+duration,
   cache: false
});
```

And I must do this with android. You have any idea to solve it? I have thought with HttpRequest but in all ways this not works

I tried with this code in Get:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://" + ip + "/cgi-bin/momentary_movement.cgi?type=GET&datatype=xml&pan="+pan+"&tilt="+tilt+"&zoom="+zoom+"&duration="+duration+"&cache=false");
```

and this code in Post:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("//" + ip + "/cgi-bin/momentary_movement.cgi");
         try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "POST"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("url", "//" + ip + "/cgi-bin/momentary_movement.cgi"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dataType", "xml" ));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", "pan="+pan+"&tilt="+tilt+"&zoom="+zoom+"&duration="+duration ));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cache", "false" ));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Comment: And the error is...? Post more than just `HttpGet` initialization.

Comment: I found the error and i'll post the code soon